# Add a call log and and contacts to my windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development, I need to add a call log and contact list to my app is there any API r how to add ? i am developing VoIP app so i need to import contact list to my project

Answer (score 1):

You can access contact list using `Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts`

```cs
  // Prints all contacts to output window

  var contacts = new Contacts();
  contacts.SearchCompleted += (s, e) => {
    foreach (var contact in e.Results) {
      Debug.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName + " - " + contact.PhoneNumbers.First().PhoneNumber);
    }
  };
  contacts.SearchAsync("", FilterKind.DisplayName, null);
```

Note you need to specifiy `ID_CAP_CONTACTS` in your manifest file.

Call logs cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contacts data, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx. You cannot access the call log.